# Common dimension filters on qlik sense mashup comtains object from multi apps

Tags: qliksense, mashup

I build a mashup on Qlik sense, and I imported objects from 2 different qlik sense apps. On those 2 different apps, there are some common dimensions (same names, same values).
Then, I would like to have a same behaviors when user filter by a common different, it means objects of both apps are reloaded with filters of selected values of same dimensions.
Is it feasible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible, unless if you develop your own code with javascript that recover the active selections and apply them to the rest of the applications used

Comment: I see. Thank you!